# Input and class based styling CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a simple way to prevent using a style when the class is 'chatInput'.
Example HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="hello" class="chatInput"/>
```

And CSS something like:

```
input[type=button&class!=chatInput], input[type=submit&class!=chatInput]{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your HTML shows a textbox, and your CSS references `button` and `submit`. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`:not` selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not):

```
input[type=button]:not(.chatInput), input[type=submit]:not(.chatInput)
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Note: IE8 and earlier do not support the :not selector. All other current browsers do: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3, you can use the [`:not()` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp):

```
input[type=button]:not(.chatInput), input[type=submit]:not(.chatInput){
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

In CSS2, and more specifically IE8 and lower, you cannot do this. You have to do something like:

```
input[type=button] {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input[type=button] .chatInput {
    /* Explicit default style */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla works with

```
:not(.classname) input {background: red;}
```

though i try to avoid negative css.  perhaps everything else (besides .chatInput) should have an additional class.

Comment: Why do you try to avoid negative CSS? Why clutter your markup when you can just exclude what you don't want to select?

Comment: dealing with them IE7's ... probably not all that relevant anymore. but they're out there...and you CAN avoid using them if you plan ahead.

Comment: @BoltClock IE8 and lower still take 10.1% of the browser market. It is a bit hard to avoid developing for it, even if Google Apps refuses to.

Comment: @Eric: Ah yes of course. Admittedly, it wasn't immediately obvious to me from the way it was written.